# How to copy sf::Font into custom pool allocated memory?

Tags: c++, memory-management, sfml, dynamic-memory-allocation

I wrote a class for pool allocator and tested it with some basic structs, `sf::Texture` and it seems to work correctly. However when I use it to copy a `sf::Font` into the allocated block I get the following error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x0F19009E (sfml-graphics-d-2.dll) in ChernoGame.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xCDCDCDCD.
```

The code that throws this error:

```
ResourceType *newResource = (ResourceType*)allocator.alloc();
ResourceType t;
*newResource = t; //error is thrown from here
```

When I use this for `sf::Texture` it works correctly, this error is thrown only when I use `sf::Font`

For sf::Font the size of the class is 76 bytes and alignment is 4 bytes, my allocator is following this and allocating it a block of 76 bytes with 4 byte alignment, I can't figure out how to resolve this error.

**Edit**: I tried it for `sf::SoundBuffer` and it is throwing similar error.

Pool Allocator initialization:

```
bool PoolAllocator::init(const unsigned int & numBlocks, const unsigned int & blockSize, const int&alignment)
{
    if (mpMemoryBlock)
    {
        return false;
    }

//  assert(alignment & (alignment - 1) == 0);

    auto expandedBlockSize = alignUp(blockSize, alignment);

    mBlockSize = expandedBlockSize;
    mAlignment = alignment;
    mBlocks = numBlocks;

    mpMemoryBlock = malloc((expandedBlockSize * numBlocks) + alignment);

    if (!mpMemoryBlock)
    {
        return false;
    }

    auto currentBlock = alignUp((uintptr_t)mpMemoryBlock, alignment);
    nextFreeBlock = currentBlock;
    auto nextBlock = currentBlock;
    mpActualBlock = (void*)currentBlock;

    for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(numBlocks); i++)
    {
        nextBlock = currentBlock + expandedBlockSize;
        auto alignedForNextPointerStorage = alignUp(currentBlock, sizeof(uintptr_t));
        *((uintptr_t*)alignedForNextPointerStorage) = nextBlock;
        currentBlock = nextBlock;
    }

    auto alignedForNextPointerStorage = alignUp(currentBlock, sizeof(uintptr_t));
    *((uintptr_t*)alignedForNextPointerStorage) = 0;

    return true;
}
```

Pool Allocator allocation :

```
void * PoolAllocator::alloc()
{
    if (*((uintptr_t*)nextFreeBlock) == 0)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    void *result = (void*)nextFreeBlock;
    nextFreeBlock = *((uintptr_t*)alignUp(nextFreeBlock, sizeof(uintptr_t)));
    return result;
}
```

Pool Allocator deallocation:

```
void PoolAllocator::dealloc(void* address)
{
    auto nextPointer = alignUp((uintptr_t)address, sizeof(uintptr_t));
    if ((alignUp((uintptr_t)address, mAlignment) == (uintptr_t)address) && (mpActualBlock <= address) && !((uintptr_t)address >= ((uintptr_t)mpActualBlock + (mBlocks * mBlockSize))))
    {
        *(uintptr_t*)nextPointer = nextFreeBlock;
        nextFreeBlock = nextPointer;
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Illegal deallocation of memory address : " + (uintptr_t)address);
    }

}
```

Comment: can you show your class?

Comment: How do you actually initialize these instances? Looks to me like you're skipping SFML's constructor for `sf::Font` by just casting your memory. Many SFML constructors are non-trivial and as such you can't just skip them.

Comment: @Mario That's the reason why I create ResourceType t and copy it in the allocated block, that should copy a default constructed object t into newResource right?

Comment: There's your reason for the crash, writing an answer. :)

Comment: @LorenceHernandez added important poolallocator functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, you're "initializing" these new object instances by simply deep copying the whole objects.

While this will work fine with C structs, it has a tendency to break for non-trivial C++ classes that will do their own memory assignment.

Imagine the following two simple classes:

```
class A {
    int number = 5;
};

class B {
    int *number;
    B() : number(new int()) { *number = 5; }
    ~B() { delete number; }
}
```

Let's now assume you create an object of class `A` and copy it:

```
A a1;
A *a2 = reinterpret_cast<A*>(new char[sizeof(A)]);
memcpy(a2, &a1, sizeof(A));
```

You'll essentially end up with two objects of class `A`.

Now let's repeat this with `B`:

```
B b1;
B *b2 = reinterpret_cast<A*>(new char[sizeof(B)]);
memcpy(b2, &b1, sizeof(B));
```

Seems like this work as well? Indeed, it does. However, once either object is destroyed directly (or goes out of scope), the other will break as well, causing an access violation. Why? Let's expand the example above with a scope:

```
B *b2 = reinterpret_cast<A*>(new char[sizeof(B)]);
{
    B b1;
    memcpy(b2, &b1, sizeof(B));
}
```

So after this code is run, you assume that `b2` points to a valid instance of class `B`. It still does – the memory is allocated – but the pointer inside `b2` is no longer valid.

- When you create `b1`, its constructor will allocate space for an integer and store that pointer (`number`).
- This pointer is then copied to `b2` as well.
- Now `b1` goes out of scope, the destructor frees the allocated integer.
- Now `b2` still points to the former integer already deallocated by `b1`.
- If you now try to access the integer, things explode.

---

As a further note, what you're doing – creating a new object and copying it to your pool allocated memory – sounds like a good idea but in the end it defeats the whole purpose behind pool allocators/memory managment: You want to avoid reallocating objects in the first place.

---

Thankfully there's a mechanic built into C++ for exactly this purpose, which is called *placement new*. Utilizing this, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
#include <new>

// Other code here ...

sf::Font* myFont = new(fontAllocator.alloc()) sf::Font;

// Later to destroy the font:
myFont->~Font();
fontAllocator.dealloc(myFont);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, great explanation, as to the alternative that you suggested does `placement new` has similar overhead as compared to the `new` cause that would again defeat the purpose of pool allocator as I want to avoid the overhead caused due to `new`

Comment: @KaranJoisher There is no overhead in calling *new* or *placement new*. The "problem" is **memory fragmentation**. Read up on that topic if you want to learn more.

Comment: @KaranJoisher Short version: `new` has to find continuous memory the right size first, which will get harder the more fragmented the address space for a program is. Placement new (with pool allocators) allows you to skip this, which is the performance gain/reason.